# Calculate grand totals from IEnumerable using LINQ instead of foreach

Tags: linq, cumulative-sum

I have this class that i want to pass to my view:

```
public class AggregateProductionTotals
{
    public int TotalPieces { get; set; }
    public int TotalPallets { get; set; }
}
```

I generate my list with:

```
var dailyProductionGroup = dailyProduction
                .OrderBy(o => o.F61Bprod.WPKYFN)
                .GroupBy(g => new { g.F61Bprod.WPKYFN, g.F61Bprod.WPDOCO })
                .Select(g => new AggregateProduction
                                 {
                                     LineCode = g.Key.WPKYFN,
                                     ItemCode = g.Max(i => i.JdeItemBasic.litm),
                                     ItemDescriptionEnglish = g.Max(i => i.JdeItemBasic.dsce),
                                     ItemDescriptionLocal = g.Max(i=>i.JdeItemBasic.dsc),
                                     WorkOrder = g.Key.WPDOCO,
                                     NumberOfPallets = g.Count(),
                                     TotalPiecesOrUnits = g.Sum(s=>(int)s.F61Bprod.WPTRQT),
                                     AvergaWeight = g.Average(a=>Convert.ToInt32(a.F61Bprod.WPLOT2))
                                 });
```

I want to calculate the totals for two of the fields and put them in a new class. I currently do it like this:

```
            int totalPallets = 0;
            int totalPiecesOrUnits = 0;
            foreach (var item in dailyProductionGroup)
            {
                totalPallets += item.NumberOfPallets;
                totalPiecesOrUnits += item.TotalPiecesOrUnits;
            }
```

and then i create the class when i return the view.

How i replace the foreach with a simple LINQ to return my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.Sum`

```
var procutionTotals = new AggregateProductionTotals
{
    TotalPallets = dailyProductionGroup.Sum(i => i.NumberOfPallets),
    TotalPieces  = dailyProductionGroup.Sum(i => i.TotalPiecesOrUnits)
};
```